# Valid reasons for References of locally accessible data?

Tags: c++, reference

So I was just minding my own business looking over some code I wrote, and I noticed something I had done. I made a reference of protected data `float& px = A->p.x` I did this purely to shorten an if statement's width and make it more readable. The function was stated as a friend of the class of course, so it could access the protected data. Furthermore, there were 4 similar references.

I am wondering if this is a valid reason to make a reference.
If not are there valid reasons to create a reference which is in no way a parameter to the function being worked in.

Example:

```
void generic_function(A_class* A)
{
float& x = A->x;
//purposeful and valid code using x?
}
```

I tried to word the question as best I could, I apologize if it doesn't communicate my purpose for asking.

Edit:
As a point of importance. I am concerned with optimization for real time application design.

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? Do you mean "a good idea", or "legal with well defined behavior"?  Yes to both.

Comment: I mean legitimate reasons for doing so. So yea I guess "good idea" type reasons. I am mainly worried about optimizations as I am programming real time applications.

Comment: I like passing by pointer in class constructors, then storing the value as reference. That way it's clear to the caller that the object needs to remain valid through the new object's lifetime, but more convenient to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, this is a very valid way of using references. Any time you need a stand-in for another location in memory to shorten your code, a reference is a perfect choice. In your case, it also shortens the chain of dereferencing: if you use `x` several times, for example, in a loop, you would cut on the number of dereferences, because you would no longer need to read `A` to get to `x` inside it. The compiler may be smart enough to optimize out this dereference for you, so you shouldn't do it as a matter of micro-optimization.

Another valid reason to use a reference is to access a cached value inside a container. A common pattern for accessing cached values from `std::map` is to read the value into a reference, check it, and then assign to the reference thus bypassing a second look-up in the map. The timing of this could be significant, especially in a tight loop, so using a reference into a map can be considered an optimization technique.

Comment: Very helpful answer. If you can think of other examples I'd love to read them.

Comment: @JoshC The second part is a general pattern: you can use local references into containers to avoid copying and searching costs.

Comment: I am slightly confused on two points. What do you mean by local references, presumably references with the type of usage this whole question is about. Right? More than that though, I am confused by "references INTO containers". I am not really sure what that means, a reference that moves through the container? Or perhaps once you find a particular object you create a reference of it and thus needn't search again.

Comment: @JoshC It's the second: you look up an element inside a container once, create a reference to it, and use it several times without searching.

Answer (score 2):

A reference is only an alias for the referenced object and therefore there is no additional memory overhead or performance cost of using it inside a function like you do. If it results in a cleaner code I can't see a reason not to use it.

Comment: @JoshC: In this case a reference is resolved at compile time and so it doesn't result in any additional memory being allocated on the stack.

Comment: It is MUCH clearer; thank you. As for it not resulting in any memory being allocated on the stack, I am actually kind of impressed. That is a pleasant surprise for sure, so long as it is true in all cases of localized references.

Comment: After reading around it seems that compilers implement references the same way as pointers, where memory is concerned. So is this a special case?

Answer (score 2):

I have used this several times to do things like:

```
// logFile is optional; if set, the function will log to that file
// If it's empty, it will log to stderr
void foo(const std::string& logFile)
{
    std::ofstream file;
    std::ostream& os = (logFile.empty()) ? std::cerr : file;
    if (!logFile.empty())
    {
        file.open(logFile);
        // validate that the file opened successfully, etc.
    }

    // Then, throughout the function, I can just use os rather than writing
    // an if statement every time I log something
    os << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

**Edit**: I made the code actually valid

Comment: oh my goodness, I haven't learned to use `?` or `:` so your code is slightly confusing. It looks nice though

Comment: It's a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). It's like an if statement, but it has a value

Comment: I know what ? does, sort of, I just haven't learned to use it, one day I will. I am sure it would be reallly useful, but right now I am working learning polymorphism at its unholiest of times. It has so far given me a few headaches figuratively speaking.

Comment: @JoshC: Ah, well good luck with that :) I'll be honest, I don't use `?:` a ton, but every once in awhile it's a nice tool. The reason it's useful here is because references *have* to be initialized when they're declared (which you probably know), so I can't use a regular if statement. Unless I'm in a situation like this, I generally don't use `?:` much. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: I did not explicitly know that they had to be initialized when declared actually. I think I always do that, possibly because of compile errors so thanks for that tid bit.